# Localizable.strings in UTF-8 is working?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I am running Xcode 4.3 but the same thing works with Xcode 4.2.  Previously, Localizable.strings file had to be in UTF-16 to be picked up by iOS; UTF-8 strings file did not work.

But this morning, I created a new test project and my Localizable strings files where created in UTF-8 by XCode.  I did not realize it right away but they do work and are being used properly on the simulator, an iOS 5 iPad and a 4.3 iPad.  My question is, do you know since when this has been working?  Is this documented somewhere or do I have something messed up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been using UTF-8 strings files for some time. Never seen a problem.

<del>However, Apple does still recommend UTF-16.</del>

As of March 21, 2016, [Apple recommends UTF-8](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html)

Comment: My personal opinion is that there is absolutely no reason to use UTF-16 or -32, as they basically waste space. UTF-8 uses a variable number of bytes per characters, optimizing space usage. Not a big deal obviously, but still... Just make sure the UTF-8 files include the BOM so there is no way to misinterpret their encoding.

Comment: In practice, I've seen more trouble with BOM than without, unless you can guarantee doing all your editing in tools that are aware of it.

Comment: I'll accept your answer as it at least confirms I'm not going mad! But I clearly remember having problem with UTF-8 files in the past. Glad that they now work properly as SVN hates UTF-16 files.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having problems with UTF-8 strings files under Xcode 4.3.2 building for iPhone 5.1.

It seems certain combinations of characters ( ':' or ">" in my case ) in the translated string are causing all translations after that character to use the string in the code, not the translated string.

Comment: your answer gave me a hint :  with xcode 13.2.1, a missing semi-colon on one of the strings will produce a bogus UTF-8 error message during the copy of the Localizable.string files. sheesh ....